# LDAP / Active Directory with External Users

Tags: permissions, active-directory, ldap, openldap, authentication

**Context**

A company that uses Active Directory for a long time. Previously, admins added Domain Users Group to many resources with read access. It is not realistic to change all this.

A service, in this case a GitHub:Enterprise instance, that uses LDAP for authentication was introduced for a cooperation project with another company.

**Problem**

Creating AD accounts for the external users gives them access to many resources which they should not have access to. If we don't create AD accounts for them, they cannot access the new service.

- Is there a way to create a kind of 'decorated' proxy for AD that has some local users (the external guys) and refers to the original AD db for other users (the employees)?
- What other ways are there that could solve the access permission problem?

It is possible to set up an additional VM with either Windows or Linux to solve the problem; however, it would be preferable if that was not required.

Answer (score 3):

Typically this would be done with SAML federation.

Or you could use your openLDAP and add all the users into it as this would not allow permissions for AD.

Comment: But how can I keep e.g. the passwords synced? There is a policy in place that forces password changes every x days, so this should be reflected. If we use OpenLDAP, how can I sync this without being able to see the user's AD passwords?

Comment: I do +1 but not accept this answer because I cannot understand how this would solve my problem. Please elaborate in more detail.

Comment: With SAML, you would not ever have the Password from the "outsiders". SAML would require an "Outsider" to authenticate to an Identity Provider that you would trust. Then the user would be permitted access. Google SAML.

Comment: With openLDAP you would allow "outsiders" to register at openLDAP. The credentials would not be in AD. Again, it is not at all clear what Service "X" is or how it uses LDAP.

Comment: SAML is an XML format. I have a server that needs to authenticate. I am sorry but I fail to see how an XML format is the solution. It might be part of the solution?